Can someone layout a better pattern for conditionally rendering a UI from context?
I'm encountering issues while upgrading from the Next.js 13 Pages Router to the App Router, specifically with conditional rendering inside a React Context. Despite searching, I haven't found similar problems highlighted in other Stack Overflow posts or documentation. Could someone suggest a better pattern for this?
Here's an example of what I would use in the pages router:
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const FakeContext = createContext(defaultFakeContext);

export function FakeProvider({ children }) {
  const [isAuthed, setIsAuthed] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Simulate auth check
    setIsAuthed(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <FakeContext.Provider value={{ isAuthed, setIsAuthed }}>
      {isAuthed ? children : <div>You are not authed</div>}
    </FakeContext.Provider>
  );
}

In the above example, I conditionally render the main UI or an unauthorized message based on the isAuthed state. While this approach works locally, it fails during the build process with the App Router. Not allowed? Unrelated and I'm overlooking something? Going insane?
Any advice or resources would be greatly appreciated!

To do conditional routing based on authentication in NextJS's server-side App based router, the best and recommended mechanism is to use NextJS's middleware, as mentioned there:

Authentication and Authorization: Ensure user identity and check
session cookies before granting access to specific pages or API
routes.


Server-Side Redirects: Redirect users at the server level based on
certain conditions (e.g., locale, user role).

You create a file named middleware.js in the project's root directory and route the user to the required page based on the saved authentication cookies on the server side.
As it's a server-side component, useState or context will not work, you will have to utilize next/cookies to store the auth status.
Middleware is superior, safer, and better than the context approach as it runs even before the cached content or the routes are generated. Typically, you create two arrays of the Protected and Public routes, match the incoming request's path with the arrays and check the auth if it matches the protected route, then, render the login/no auth page based on this.

For the above mentioned problem, To render conditionally I would highly suggest to use conditional parallel routes(Note: parallel routes don't work as expected for dynamic routes), But for a normal route it works like a charm and is part of the layout.
Also, if possible I would suggest you to use server component and rely on server functions for auth related checks and flows. This would possible help you in following ways

Decouple the logic of the component hierarchy and avoid referring the context frequently.
Keeps your application in-sync with the server's state of reality rather than referring the client side state, which could potentially be stale (important especially for the auth flow)

P.S: I understand that the passed child of client component can be a server component.

Second, if you have different route paths for authenticated and un-authenticated users, then as suggested by @lalit-fauzdar in his answer, use middleware to dynamically routes the users to the respective routes.

P.S: It would be helpful if you could share the error shown.
